# Clonezilla Ubuntu 16.04 after clone missing data but server wokrs

Tags: 16.04, clonezilla

Server HP XW6400 dual CPU (Intel x64), Ubuntu 16.04.

My old HDD 350GB (512bit) need to be replaced to 2TB WD Purple (4096bit) - I am aware of performance downwards. 
I have tried i386 and amdx64 Clonezilla most recent stable versions. None of them worked.
Originally system works on 350GB & 3TB as storage (non RAID).

Once cloning is complete system boot to GUI but only guest is available. After closer inspection all my credentials - all web sites, FTP, SMB, literally all setting hasn't been copied (?). Server it self works without a doubt.

When I created user I spotted that all my data sits on the partition ext3/ext4 and is different from where system boot up.

In GUI I have My Computer and 142GB Volume ( on this partition I have all my data)

What I have done wrong?

Comment: Please explain your partition layout and what you cloned.

Comment: Please explain how you performed the cloning: For example: did you clone the whole drive or only some partitions?

Comment: Clone whole drive. To be clear I didn't use PXE. Pure clone disk to disk.

Comment: 1. Are the physical sector sizes different between the source drive and the target drive (the clone)? Is this what you mean by 'My old HDD 350GB (512bit) need to be replaced to 2TB WD Purple (4096bit)'?; 2. Is there an MSDOS partition table or a GUID partition table (GPT)? After cloning a drive with GPT you must repair the backup partition table at the tail end of the drive. You can do it with `gdisk`; -- These things can be checked with `sudo parted -ls`

Comment: 1. Yes, this are physical sector sizes.

2. MSDOS.

I have included screen shots from 'parted -ls'
old disk - https://ibb.co/mWNCXe
new disk - https://ibb.co/mtZgQz

Comment: It turns out that I had to update grub to restore my system. Because I have moved my home directory to another partition, server couldn't start with my credentials.

On sda1 I had raw system and on sda5 system with all my data.

Answer (score 0):

I have used disk to disk clone.

[partition layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV2MX.png)